# Read pixel values of a raster image for given coordinates stored in a CSV file

Tags: python, raster, geopandas, rasterio, pandas

I was trying to find the pixel values of several pixels whose coordinates are known. I did that in this way:

```
import rasterio

lons = [66.979, 69.2979, 67.2979 ]
lats = [36.5854, 40.9854, 37.9854]
with rasterio.open('P.tif') as src:
    vals = [x for x in src.sample(zip(lons, lats))]
```

All the pixel values are stored in variable vals as it was intended to be. Here, I want to give lons and lats from a CSV file. However, I was not succesfull in doing that. The code I tried:

```
import rasterio
points = pd.read_csv('coordinates.csv')
for i in range(0,sz[0]):
    lons = points.iloc[[i],[0]]
    lats = points.iloc[[i],[1]] 
    with rasterio.open('image.tif') as src:
        vals = [x for x in src.sample(zip(lons, lats))]
```

Comment: I gave the answer yesterday. Did you delete it? Well, you can try this ```points=points.values()```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import rasterio
import pandas as pd

Vals=pd.read_csv('coordinates.csv')
Vals=Vals.values
lons = Vals[:,0] 
lats = Vals[:,1] 
with rasterio.open('P.tif') as src:
    vals = [x for x in src.sample(zip(lons, lats))]
```